# Help with the convergence of an improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Consider a continuous function $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \int_{0}^{x}f(x)dx = 0$.

I would like to know if under this condition we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \int_{0}^{x}f^2(x)dx = 0$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, the first condition does not imply the second.  If $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^x f(t)^2dt=0$ then  $f(t)=0$ for all $t \in [0, \infty)$, except possibly for a set of measure 0.  This is not required for the first condition.  Can you give an example where the first condition holds for a nontrivial function $f$? (i.e., one that is not almost-always zero?)

Comment: Hint: alternating series